# Winning strategy using Dynamic Programing

Tags: graphs, dynamic-programming

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a DAG and let $v_0\in V$.
Alice and Bob are playing a game in which every player has his own turn and Bob is starting. In every turn $i$, the player is picking an edge $e=(v_i,x)$, then $x$ become $v_{i+1}$ and then it becomes the other player's turn. The player which doesn't have an edge to choose (the vertex $v_i$ has no out edges) is losing.

Propose an algorithm which determines if Bob has a winning strategy.

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a vertex $v \in V$, let $W(v)$ be the following predicate: "a player starting at $v$ wins". If $N(v)$ is the set of outward neighbors of $v$, then
$$
W(v) = \bigvee_{u \in N(v)} \lnot W(u),
$$
where the empty disjunction is simply false.

This suggests a strategy to compute $W(v_0)$ using dynamic programming.